# Show command missing red dots from one of the function

Tags: plotting, graphics

I am facing an issue when trying to use Show command to show multiple graphs within one graph. Show command only shows red dot from one of the graph.

```
u3b = Plot[f1[a, x], {x, -10, 20}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, 
    Point[{x, 0} /. NSolve[f1[a, x]]]}]
```

[image: first graph with red dot]

```
dydx = D[x^3 - a x^2 - x + 1, x];

Plot[dydx, {x, -10, 20}, PlotStyle -> Blue, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
u3c = Plot[dydx, {x, -10, 20}, PlotRange -> Automatic, 
  PlotStyle -> Blue, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{x, 0} /. NSolve[dydx]]}]

Show[u3b, u3c, PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

[image: second graph with red dot and Show command that left the red dot out]

Comment: post your code (not a picture only)

Comment: ok, I just added the code.

Comment: `Show` will use the options of the first argument and thus drop the second occurence of `Epilog`. You need to add those graphics primitives once more.

Comment: Adding it in Show or where?

Answer (score 3):

For example:

```
f1[a_, x_] := x^3 - a x^2 - x + 1
a = 4;
epilog1 = {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{x, 0} /. NSolve[f1[a, x]]]};
epilog2 = {PointSize[Large], Green, Point[{x, 0} /. NSolve[D[f1[a, x], x]]]};

u3b = Plot[f1[a, x], {x, -10, 20}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}];
u3c = Plot[D[f1[a, t], t] /. t -> x, {x, -10, 20}];

Show[u3b, u3c, Epilog -> Join[epilog1, epilog2]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There are in fact a lot of ways to achieve the same result. Another example is:

```
Show[u3b, u3c, Graphics@Join[epilog1, epilog2]]
```

The most common problem is that `Show[]` takes its plot range from the first argument, so you need to be careful about setting it right.

Comment: One might further point out a common problem with `Show` is that the graphics options in the first argument override options in subsequent arguments. In this case, that means that the second `Epilog` is ignored.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yup. That was Yves' comment at the question

Comment: I didn't notice.  Your answer was just that compelling. :)  (+1, btw)